# Verifying proof of closed under scalar multiplication for U = {$xg(x) + (1-x)h(x) | g(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{P}_2$}

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Can anybody verify that my proof that set U is closed under scalar multiplication is sufficient?

Set:  U = {$xg(x) + (1-x)h(x) | g(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{P}_2$}
where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $\le$ 2.

Proof:
Let a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and g,h $\in \mathbb{P}_2$
then $ag(x) = axg(x) = a(xg(x)) \in U$
and $ah(x) = a(1-x)h(x) = a[(1-x)h(x)] \in U$
Thus, U is closed under scalar multiplication. $\blacksquare$

EDIT:

Proof:
Let a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and p,q $\in \mathbb{P}_2$
then $a(xp(x) + (1-x)q(x))$  = $axp(x) + a(1 - x)q(x)$  $\in$ U
Which is of the form $xg(x) + (1-x)h(x)$
Note that $aq(x), ap(x) \in \mathbb{P}_2$
Thus, U is closed under scalar multiplication. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your proof is actually untrue, as with the third.

Hint: Your goal should be to prove that the expression, $ x g(x) + (1-x) h(x) $, when multiplied by $a$, still takes the same form $x p(x) + (1-x) q(x) $, where $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{P}_2$. That shows that $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: The first equalities $ag(x)=axg(x)$ and $ah(x)=a(1-x)h(x)$ are untrue.

Comment: Thank you, I have rewritten my proof.  Does this make sense?

Comment: You should have another step reminding the reader that $aq(x),ap(x) \in \mathbb{P}_2$. Then your proof should be complete.